# How to automatically test playframework evolutions

Tags: playframework, automated-tests

We are using play 1.2.x DB evolutions feature. I want to have the scripts to create and develop schema being tested in play auto-test

So I need an empty DB before tests suite.

I thought about:

- registering @OnApplicationStartup listener that could delete all
  structures in DB (which would require some dirty code probably), and
  let db evolutions do the rest. But play evolutions are as well an
  @OnApplicationStartup and I don't know how to make sure my listener
  will be the first. This could be overcome with another hack - calling
  DB evolutions from code.
- dropping and recreating DB with some script - before running
  auto-test, but that doesn't make my test be always the test I want. e.g. I need to always remember to use my script not only auto-test. This script will not be executed when executing test from eclipse.

Are there any other options?

Or maybe someone can suggest any other solution for testing this stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler: use an in-memory database (compatible in syntax with your prod database so that the SQL works fine).

You'll have a new db each run, and evolutions will execute always.

Comment: Problem is mysql mode in h2 is not 100% compatible with real mysql syntax - for example in terms of alter table command. but I may overcome it somehow. and this might be the best option for now.